# How to Load a Tensorflow 2.0's tfrecords File?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I have a .tfrecords file that stores my serialised data. How can I re-load it next time? It is impractical to generate it fro raw data each time when it is needed.
Note that I tried TFRecordReader at
[enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/t-f-record-reader) but it does not work at all

tf prompts

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'TFRecordReader'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to read tfrecord files in TensorFlow 2.0:

1. Use [tf.compat.v1.TFRecordReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/TFRecordReader).
2. Use [tf.data.TFRecordReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset?version=stable)